# Django, recently added Foreign key value is not recognised as valid in form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm writing django app, in which I have form, which allows adding new foreign key values, to multiple choice field proided by autocomplete-light. The problem is, that recently added values is not "valid", when I try to save form with them.
They are not even when I try to use them in new forms. I see that value was written to SQLite database, but it can't be used till django app restart, is that some common noob django user fail, or is that some kind of bug? I can provide some code, but I have no idea, when I do something wrong.

Code:

model:

```
class AilmentDict(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'ailment_dict'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.name)
    def __str__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.name)
```

form:

```
class AilmentDictForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}), max_length=30, label='Objaw', required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = AilmentDict
```

view:

```
@login_required
def add_ailment(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = AilmentDictForm()
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form = AilmentDictForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            ailment = form.save(commit=True)
            return render(request, 'examinations/add', {'added': ailment})
        else:
            print(form.errors)

    return render(request, 'examinations/addailment.html', {'form': form})
```

add:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
opener.dismissAddAnotherPopup(
    window,
    "{{ added.id }}",
    "{{ added.name }}"
);
</script>
```

autocomplete_light registration:

```
autocomplete_light.register(AilmentDict,
                            search_fields = ['^id', 'name'],
                            add_another_url_name = 'addailment',
                            attrs={
                                'placeholder': '',
                                'data-autocomplete-minimum-characters': 1,
                            },
                            widget_attrs={
                                'data-widget-maximum-values': 0,
                            },
                            )
```

Field in Examination Form:

```
ailments = autocomplete_light.MultipleChoiceField('AilmentDictAutocomplete', label='Objawy', required=False)
```

I don't know if You need anything more.

Comment: You need to post the code for us to help you!

Comment: Code posted. Do you need anymore? I don't really know where I failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about autocomplete-light, but I suspect you should be using a [`ModelMultipleChoiceField`](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/stable-2.x.x/api.html#modelmultiplechoicefield) rather than a `MultipleChoiceField`.